# how to get access_token of instagram api

Tags: cordova, instagram, instagram-api

I'm developing a phonegap application. 
I'm trying to get the access_token which is generated from instagram. the problem is here that , how to get this token from redirect_uri!? 
I don't have self implemented server , so what kind of redirect_uri I should use to get the token in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be just redirect to your *localhost*.